# PHP & Delphi COM+ DLL & Serial port

Tags: php, delphi, com, serial-port

That's my most recent problem...

I have here some legacy COM+ DLLs that were developed using Delphi 5. One of those DLLs has a method to write stuff on COM Serial ports using the following code:

```
AssignFile(fport,'COM1');
Rewrite(fport);
Write(fport,'some command');
CloseFile(fport);
```

When we started coding the front end to use PHP, we used a WebService on IIS to access the COM+ DLL. I didn't know then that I could use the COM class in PHP to do it. But it was working fine.

So today I changed the php to use the COM class and got rid of the IIS. The DLL is called, the function is executed, but the serial port communication does not work at all. I tried to put some `try..except` on Delphi code but no exception is thrown.

Maybe is something related to privileges that php process doesn't have to access the serial port?

Thanks in advance for any clue!

Answer (score 0):

The DLL was registered on the machine using `regsvr32` and there was the error. I installed it into the Component Services and everything is OK now.

Comment: I also suspect you've created a package in Component Services, and chose activation as a dedicated process, that runs under a designated user-account, *thus* giving you access to COM1, since from the default NT-service account you can't access ports.

Comment: Yeap. Dedicated process and designated user-account... You are right!